# Understanding shift operations on too small types

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I had an issue in my code with bitwise shifting in C that I boiled down to the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char a = 1;
  int i=0;
  uint64_t b;
  for(i=0; i<64; i++)
  {
    b=0;
    printf("i=%d\n", i);
    b = (a<< ((uint64_t) i));
    printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", b);
  }
  return 0;

}
```

For reasons not apparent in this MWE `a` is a `char` from which I wanted to generate the powers of 2 up to 2^63. It failed because something weird was going on because `a` as not `uint64_t`. The obvious fix was

```
b = ((uint64_t)a<< ((uint64_t) i))
```

To understand what exactly was going on I wrote above MWE example from which I get the output (shown partially):

```
i=30  
1073741824  
i=31  
18446744071562067968  
i=32  
1  
i=33  
2
```

Now I am wondering how can I explain the jump from `i=30` to `i=31`? And how does it end up being 1 again at `i=32`?

If it is of interest, I compiled above code using gcc (`gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.8.5`)

Comment: `%lu` does not specify a 64-bit integer (unless you have 64-bit `unsigned long`s) so the program is undefined.

Comment: You have multiple cases of *undefined behavior*. For starters, remember that `a` will be [promoted to an `int`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) which is a *signed* 32-bit type. Then remember how computers typically handles negative numbers ([two's complement]([promoted to an `int`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions))) and lastly remember that shifting a value more than the available bits is leading to UB.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks, I actually didn't know that shifting was actually undefined when I exceed the number of bits. Guess that just never happened in my code before. Good to know though

Comment: @molbdnilo `sizeof(unsigned long)` gives 8 bytes on my system, but you are right to point that out

Comment: You seem to be changing your code - with the current code, modified as shown, I cannot reproduce your output.

Comment: @TobySpeight the only "significant" change I made was change the format specifier to `PRIu64`. But since the behaviour is `undefined`, it is very likely that you cannot reproduce my output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of answers already address that your code have undefined behavior. Therefore it doesn't in general make sense to reason about what happened (as anything could have happened...).

But.... sometimes it's actually quite interesting to do anyway - keeping in mind that it is **pure guessing** and **not guaranteed to be correct** and **highly system dependent** and ....

So with all the disclaimers in place...

> Where could the odd number 18446744071562067968  come from?

Let's assume 32 bit `int`and also notice that your `char a = 1;` could just as well be `int a = 1;` because of integer promotion. So we can write:

```
int a = 1;
int as = a << 31;  // Undefined behavior here as 1*2^31 can't be stored in 32 bit int
uint64_t b = as;
printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", b);
```

Output:

```
18446744071562067968
```

Hmmm.... there we have that mysterious 18446744071562067968  but why?

Let's do one more printing:

```
int a = 1;
int as = a << 31;  // Undefined behavior here
uint64_t b = as;
printf("%d\n", as);
printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", b);
```

Output

```
-2147483648
18446744071562067968
```

So `as` is negative so we really did:

```
uint64_t b = -2147483648;
```

Since b is unsigned the above is calculated as:

```
uint64_t b = UINT64_MAX + 1 - 2147483648;  // which is 18446744071562067968
```

So now we know where 18446744071562067968 came from. Not that mysterious after all.

But this leaves another question - why is `as` negative?

Hmmm.... let's do one more printing:

```
int a = 1;
int as = a << 31;  // Undefined behavior here
uint64_t b = as;
printf("%d\n", as);
printf("%x\n", as);  // Print as in hex
printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", b);
```

Output:

```
-2147483648
80000000
18446744071562067968
```

So in hex `as` is `80000000` which is in fact a `1` left shifted 31 times. So the processor simply did what we asked for, i.e. `1 << 31` It is undefined by the C standard but your/my processor was simply implemented to do like that - other machines may do something else.

`80000000` as a 32 bit 2's complement is `-2147483648` and thereby we know why `as` is negative.

Answer (score 3):

You're performing a shift that's greater than the size of the type in question.

First, `a` (which is of type `char`) is promoted to type `int`.  This is detailed in section 6.3.1.1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The following may be used in an expression wherever an `int` or `unsigned
>   int` may be used:
>
> - An object or expression with an integer type (other than `int` or `unsigned int`) whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to
>     the rank of `int` and `unsigned int`.
> - A bit-field of type `_Bool`, `int`, `signed int`, or `unsigned int`.
>
> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted
>   by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`;
>   otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the
>   *integer promotions*. All other types are unchanged by the integer
>   promotions.

Assuming an `int` is 32 bits on your system, shifting left by more than 30 bits invoked undefined behavior.  This is detailed in section 6.5.7 of the standard:

> *3* The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. **If the value
>   of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the
>   width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined**
>
> *4* The result of **E1 << E2** is E1 left-shifted **E2** bit positions; vacated
>   bits are filled with zeros. If **E1** has an unsigned type, the value of
>   the result is **E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup>**, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value
>   representable in the result type. **If E1 has a signed type and
>   nonnegative value, and E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup> is representable in the result type,
>   then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is
>   undefined.**

Comment: Hmmm, as the spec is based on _values_, it appears `char a = 0; a << 31;` or even `a << 1000` would be well defined.  True that in OP's case `a == 1`, but your post with the citations made me re-think the "shifting left by more than 30 bits invoked undefined behavior." applicability as it appears to be value dependent.

Comment: @chux For shifts of less than the bit size for signed types then yes, whether or not the behavior is undefined depends on the value being shifted.  However, *any* shift greater than or equal to the bit size is undefined, per 6.5.7p3.

Comment: It certainly looks that per 6.5.7p3, `0<<1000` is defined.

Answer (score 3):

The (somewhat unexpected) rule that kicks in here is that, when it comes to `<<`,

> the type of the result is that of the promoted left operand

This means that the type of  `a << (uint64_t) i` is an `int`, as the `char` type for `a` is automatically widened to an `int`.

It appears that your `int` is a 32 bit 2's complement signed type. Therefore for `i` greater or equal to 31, the behaviour of the expression is *undefined*.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is an undefined behavior.

[C99](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.5.7p3)

> shift-expression:
>
> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to **the width of the promoted left operand**, the behavior is undefined.

Here your `char a` is promoted to `int`[See [here](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.3.1.1p2) why]. And in your machine, the width of `int` is not bigger than 63, thus according to the standard, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Assuming 32 (or inferior) bits `int`.

Comment: On a platform with a 128 bit `int`, the code as presented would be absolutely fine.

Comment: @Bathsheba Curious, do you know of any 128 bit `long long` or `intmax_t` implementations yet?  I know of various platforms that have some squishy `__int128` _extended integer_ type, but not as  regular integer types.   Maybe someday?

Comment: @chux: Me neither sadly. But what I really want is a "native" decimal floating point type.